# User has too much permission

Tags: 2013, permissions, office-web-apps, security-token-service

My issue is different than most.  My user 'spdo' is in the group SP Visitors. They should have access to the following...
Root > Subsite > Subsite (and it should end there) however they can see doc libraries in the last subsite which their access has been removed.
So my question is why is Sharepoint 2013 (on Server 2012 and bound to a separate web apps server) offering view rights at the doc library level?  Is it a token thing?  Is it a zone thing?
Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the user has been added to "Policy for Web Application". You can check it within Central Administration -> Web Applications.

If a user has full permissions granted here he can simply access everything.